# DB2 SQL error while SQL passthrough using SAS

Tags: sql, sas, db2

I have been running a SAS query using passthrough facility to access data from db2 database. The date format is shown (numeric example) as 01FEB2021. I am using the date range using between '2021-02-01' and '2021-02-16'.
I am getting following error in SAS log:

ERROR: CLI cursor extended fetch error: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0413N  Overflow occurred during numeric data type conversion.  SQLSTATE=22003

Can someone help me fix this error?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What are the columns in your pass through `SELECT` ? Is one of the columns of type `BIGINT` or `DECFLOAT` ?  If so, there is your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume one of the columns being `SELECT`ed is of type `BIGINT` or `DECFLOAT`

- If so, there is your problem.  In your `SELECTY` you will want to:

  - cast to a DOUBLE which SAS can handle, or
  - use a function to select the character representation of the oversized column

    - `BIGINT(my-column)`, or
    - `DECFLOAT(my-column)`, or
    - `DECFLOAT_FORMAT(my-column, format-string)`

Comment: Thanks Richard. Cast function worked for me. I appreciate you taking time to respond to my query. Thank you.